# opencv: using cout with Mat object throwing exception

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I needed to print my Mat object and the programm throws an exception... The project is really simply: creating Mat object and printing by using cout - just like in OpenCV tutorial:

```
#include <core/core.hpp>
#include <highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat O = Mat::ones(2, 2, CV_32F);
    cout << "O = " << endl << " " << O << endl << endl;

    // Point2f P(5, 1);
    // cout << "Point (2D) = " << P << endl << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The exception says: `Unhandled exception at 0x59430671 (msvcp100d.dll) in printingTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000`. Console shows only

```
O = [
```

Precisely it stops on "operations.hpp" at:

```
static inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Mat& mtx) { Formatter::get()->write(out, mtx); return out; }
```

It seems "out" to be empty, but does someone know why? Tutorial says it should work...

I had earlier similar problem with throwing exception and I solved it here:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/5113/problem-with-reading-image-to-mat/

Is it possible that there is another environmental variable conflict? or maybe a collision 'cause I'm using VS2012 and there's OpenCV only for v10?

The thing with Point2f which is commented works normally.

Comment: You are using OpenCV built with VS10. The `ostream operator <<` in the DLL is using the operator from VC 10 Runtime. While you are calling the `ostream operator <<` from VC 11 Runtime. The DLLs are conflicting.

Comment: As a side note, it is not a good practice to name your variables using names such as "O", "l" etc.

Comment: @sgar91 there are only VC10 libs for OpenCv. Is it possible that only this doesn't work and everything else is going fine? That's sad..

Comment: @lightalchemist thanks, but as I mentioned I copied it from OpenCV tutorial :)

Comment: `ostream` is one of the core classes of the CPP Runtime. Its implementation differs in different versions of VC. The OpenCV code will work but features of the CPP runtime will conflict. An alternate approach (tough one) is to re-compile OpenCV using VS 2012

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine here with VS2010. Make sure you are linking the correct libraries (release vs. debug). If this does not help try to reinstall openCV or make your own build on VS2012, preparing it with cmake, from the sources.

Comment: That's the point, I was searching Internet and sometimes at someone's computer it's working and sometimes not. Linked libraries are OK. I made also build at CMake, still the same error...

Comment: You really recompiled the whole library with VS2012 using the output of cmake and use these self build libs?

Comment: Yes, I have. Maybe I did something wrong? I set the "where is the source code" (C:\opencv - that's where it is) and "where to build the binaries" I just created a new folder in C:\opencv\opencv_debug. I chose Visual Studio 11 as a generator and then configure, setting the missing path for ipp and tbb (because I will use it in future), configure again and then generate. CMake created OpenCV solution so i run it in VS. Then in my project I set in Properties, in Linker C:\opencv\opencv_debug\lib\Debug. PAth to the includes reminds the same.

Comment: It works !! Dobi & sgar91 thank you :) You see, I build it in CMake a few days ago, but I didn't change PATH variable... (no, I'm not blonde :P) It came to my mind right now. I had also add there path to tbb's dlls. And now it works. What a relieve ;)